# htaccess rewrite one file type with get variables

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, video

i think header is confusing, here is the situation.

i host some video files and want to use on my website. but only on my website. if you realized facebook did this. but we dont have servers like them -nginx i guess-.

finally i want to redirect all requests to a certain page. like that

if someone request that

```
http://www.blabla.com/videos/1.mpg?hash=12345&expire=1234567
```

htaccess redirect that request to

```
http://www.blabla.com/check.php?file=videos/1.mpg&hash=12345&expire=1234567
```

but also if someone type

```
http://www.blabla.com/videos/1.mpg
```

it is also redirect to check.php

```
http://www.blabla.com/check.php?file=videos/1.mpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hash=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/videos/(.*)$ /check.php?file=videos/$2 [R=302,L,QSA]
```

Now your rewriteRule will only be applied if query string contains hash=xxxxx

use R=301 if you want users to be redirected permanently

Comment: thx for reply. i tried similar code. redirect to a php file and check hash code. then read original file (with file_get_contents) and send to the user (with echo). but is using a lot of cpu load. and server locked down. how would i check that hash code without using too much perfomance. htaccess can check it?

Comment: what do mean checking hash code ? you mean to see if its present in url?

Comment: here is the my final wish [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197970/is-there-any-chance-to-use-that-nginx-httpaccesskeymodule-in-litespeed-or-apache). hash code in its query string. i want to check that.

Comment: alright your answer correct but if you have a lot of hit, you cant use this method effectively. thanks anyway.