# Is there any chance to use that nginx HttpAccessKeyModule in litespeed or apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, litespeed

can i use nginx's HttpAccessKeyModule in litespeed or apache. or do you know any module or htaccess rule which doing same job?

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessKeyModule